# Metro menu HTML/CSS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am currently working on a website just for the funs and even more just to learn the basics ^^

So i want to create a Metro menu (indeedy inspired by win 8 X3 ) so i got the divs movable with Jquery. Now i want to possition them all the right way:

```
[  big block  ]
[small] [small]
[  big block  ]
```

etc.

i got the first 2 row's just perfect.
Now the problem is the following:
My 2th big block will be placed like this:

```
[  big block  ]
[small] [small] [  big block  ]
```

or just behind other divs :/

here is some code stuffs to make it more clear what i mean XD:
[CSS]

```
    <style>
#facebook{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:462px;
    height:174px;
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    background:none;
    background-image:url(buttons/facebook.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

#agenda{
    float:left;
    margin-left:18px;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:223px;
    height:146px;
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    background:none;
    background-image:url(buttons/Agenda.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

#contacts{
    float: none;
    width: 462px;
    height: 174px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background: none;
    background-image: url(buttons/Contacts.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

and the HTML looks a bit like:

```
<div id="facebook" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<div id="desktop" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<div id="agenda" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<div id="contacts" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
```

so if anyone knows a good tutorial on how to place them divs the right way or just some explanation on how-to that would be amazing!^_^

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi For this you can use a main container for your menu and insid this create divs with two different classes. In my case `bb` (big-block) and `sm` (small-block).

Then you can add CSS styles. Review this demo and ask any question **http://jsfiddle.net/AKr3k/6/**

**Edit**

In your CSS try to add `clear:both` for your big blocks.